# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics when executing VS Code

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

When executing the sample application created by gradle init I get the following error when executed in VSCode:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
at hello.AppKt.main(App.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 1 more

The execution works OK with `gradle build` and `gradle run`.

I'm  using the standard build.gradle.kts script as generated by `gradle init`

```
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Kotlin application project to get you started.
 * For more details on building Java & JVM projects, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/building_java_projects.html in the Gradle documentation.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm Plugin to add support for Kotlin.
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.8.20"

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    application
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use the Kotlin JUnit 5 integration.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5")

    // Use the JUnit 5 integration.
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.2")

    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-runtime:1.2.71")
}

// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(18))
    }
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass.set("hello.AppKt")
}

tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Adding a implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20") to the dependencies doesn't change the issue.